Has anyone used Natural Language Processing to query an Itunes database or its xml file?
As per title. I want to ask questions like:

Which artists with one or more albums that have a 4 or 5 star rating have released a new album in the last 12 months and list the albums.

Generate a playlist from songs with 3 stars or higher where the
theme is sailing. etc


I have looked around the web and tried querying AI bots like Copilot but nothing useful has been found.


Which artists with one or more albums that have a 4 or 5 star rating have released a new album in the last 12 months and list the albums.

That sounds like Table Question Answering (Table QA), i.e.  answering a question about an information on a given table. It's an entire subfield in NLP, e.g. see https://patents.google.com/patent/US20220374426A1/en for some pre-LLM model, and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2408.09174 for LLMs.
Also there is a fair amount of work on tabular learning, e.g.:

CARTE: Pretraining and Transfer for Tabular Learning
A Survey on Deep Tabular Learning
TabularFM: An Open Framework For Tabular Foundational Models

